# Packaging PySide with PyInstaller

Tags: pyside

I am trying to package a pyside + QML application within a single file.
When I run the executable I get this error

> ImportError: could not import module 'PySide.QtNetwork'
>   Fatal Python error: can't initialize module QtDeclarative

Does someone have a clue ?

PS : I am on Windows

Comment: [**cx_freeze**](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) has never let me down. Try that.

Answer (score 3):

try to import module explicity:

import PySide.QtNetwork

Answer (score 1):

Just want to say this solved an issue I had packaging a pySide application with pyImporter. I was getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 93, in
>      File "c:\Users\Rizzo the
>   Rat\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line
>   409, in load_module
>       module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple) ImportError: could not import module 'PySide.QtXml'

until I added this line:

```
from PySide import QtXml
```